# Llenar una lista de diccionarios Python

Tags: python, django, lista, diccionarios

Estoy intentando crear una lista con varios diccionarios, pero cuando ejecuto el código que realice solo me llena la lista con el ultimo diccionario.

```
consulta = programacion.objects.filter(Q(codigo_recurso__recurso__icontains='01. TRUMPF') & ~Q(estado_job='Cancelado') & ~Q(estado_job='Finalizado')).values('pk', 'programacion', 'codigo_hijo', 'Observacion', 'calibre_espesor', 'pedido', 'orden_produccion',                                                                                                                                  'actual_start_time', 'actual_end_time', 'descripcion_hijo', 'rendimiento', 'cantidad_inicial', 'fecha_entrega', 'codigo_recurso', 'descripcion_orden_produccion', 'estado_job').order_by('-estado_job','programacion','orden_produccion')
                
results =[]                    
trumpf={}
                
for i in consulta:
             
    codigo=i['codigo_hijo']
    paquete = i['programacion']
                    
    cantidades = programacion.objects.filter(Q(programacion=paquete) & Q(codigo_hijo=codigo) & Q(codigo_recurso__recurso__icontains='01.TRUMPF')).values('pk','codigo_hijo').aggregate(cantidades=Sum('cantidad_inicial'))
                    
    for a in cantidades.values():
            trumpf['Pk']=i['pk']
            trumpf['Codigo_hijo']= codigo
            trumpf['Paquete']= paquete
            trumpf['cantidad'] = a
                        
            results.append(trumpf)
```

Comment: Quieres decir el último pero repetido muchas veces?

Comment: Tengo que llenarla con varios registros diferentes que se generan en la consulta pero cuando agrego los diccionarios a la lista, me repite muchas veces el ultimo diccionario :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### El problema

Las variables python son referencias a objetos guardados en memoria.

Cuando haces por ejemplo:

```
diccionario = {}
lista = []
lista.append(diccionario)
```

lo que se ha guardado en la lista es una referencia al objeto al que estaba haciendo referencia la variable `diccionario`. Ese objeto ahora mismo es un diccionario vacío. Sin embargo si seguidamente haces:

```
diccionario["prueba"] = 3
```

entonces ese objeto-diccionario ha cambiado y ahora tiene una clave "prueba" y un valor 3. Ya que la lista simplemente albergaba una referencia a ese objeto, si la imprimes verás el objeto cambiado:

```
print(lista)
----
[{'prueba': 3}]
```

Naturalmente si haces de nuevo `lista.append(diccionario)` estás metiendo la misma referencia dos veces. Los dos elementos de la lista "apuntan" al mismo diccionario que contiene ahora `{'prueba': 3}`

Gráficamente se ve así (creado con [Python Tutor](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=diccionario%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0Alista%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0Alista.append%28diccionario%29%0Adiccionario%5B%22prueba%22%5D%20%3D%203%0Alista.append%28diccionario%29%0Aprint%28lista%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=5&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) ejecutando el código antes mostrado)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que está pasando con tu código. En cada iteración del bucle, estás modificando el diccionario al que "apunta" la variable `trumpf`, y metiendo en la lista otra referencia más, pero siempre al mismo objeto-diccionario. Así que todos los elementos de la lista son iguales (pues apuntan al mismo objeto), y ya que ese objeto lo modificas en cada iteración del bucle, al final sólo se ve el último valor.

### La solución

Debes crear un nuevo "objeto-diccionario" vacío en cada iteración del bucle. Así `trumpf` apuntará en cada iteración a un diccionario nuevo.

La solución es tan simple como mover la inicialización `trumpf = {}` al interior del bucle `for a ...`

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Me has resuelto el problema :)